# 4GB temporary system files showing up on desktop for no understandable reason

Tags: windows-7, malware-detection

There are 4GB temporary system files called "BITEA#.tmp" e.g. BITEA5.tmp   showing up on my Desktop folder just this last week. Does anyone know if this may be caused by malware recording screen or file information?

I have anti-virus and malware protection.

Comment: if you do the following: WinKey + R -> cmd -> ok -> type echo %temp% then press enter. What does it spit out?

Comment: The default AppData\Local\Temp

Comment: Ok, does it appear randomly, or can you predict when it will appear? What happens when you delete it?

Comment: I'm able to delete it. It does not appear at a particular time. I just notice it come out of nowhere

Comment: It may be hard to find the source then, but check out diskmon
from Sysinternals.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896646.aspx